# Embedded VFP not showing on popup

Tags: visualforce, create-records, page-layout, popup

[Since no one has suggested a better solution to my question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/239293/custom-components-in-page-layout) I'm currently trying to include a custom component into a standard layout using a visual force page.

I was able to create the VFP and add it to my standard layout.

The problem that came up now is the following:

When opening the page which have my VFP embedded I'm able to see it correctly:[image: Viewing]

The 42$ and stuff there are my VFP page.

But when I'm trying to create that object (so a modal open and I have to fill in the field) the embedded VFP is not showing:
[image: Creating]

Is there a way to make that Embedded VFP visible and accessible during the creation of my record?

And will I be able to retrieve the value (of that specific VPF embedded element) from an apex trigger in some way?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Sorry for hiding all the fields name, but I'm unsure of my company policies about this stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior.

The page layout has a *different* behavior when you are creating/editing a record vs. viewing a record.

When you are creating/editing a record, the embedded components are not displayed but only those fields which are directly associated to the object. Thus if you have an embedded VF page on your page layout, it will be never shown on a create/edit screen.

As an example, you don't see Formula fields, or say related lists when you create/edit a record, but only when you are viewing the details of the record.

Comment: I can try to formulate my problem in a different way.
I have a field which needs to behave like a pickup list but with search functionality. So I have used the Strike lookup component. Now my problem is that I can not use this component as I can use a normal lookup field. Thus while creating a record the user cannot populate that field.
Is there a better approach to this problem?

Comment: Not completely following, but if you have a lookup field, you can use it while creating a record. However if you have any issues around that specifically, you may like to open a new question with more details and the specific issue so that someone can help you. As for this question, you don't have an option really to be able to display an embedded visual force page on standard page layout while creating a new record.

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/239371/picklist-500-records-not-very-user-friendly Posted my full question here, thanks for helping me out!